# C# garbage collection in intense memory using application

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have an image editor program. Many of the editor actions requires to copy an image in memory. The images can be very large, and edits can be done several times in second, so memory usage is intense.

I accurately `Dispose()` every unused image. But when I profiled my application, I noticed then during intense editing operations the memory consumption growth (I even got `OutOfMemoryException` few times). After some seconds of inactivity it returns to regular value, so there are no memory leaks. So I think the reason is that garbage collection happens too seldom. I put `GC.Collect()` after each edit operation and it helped, the memory consumption is stable now.

However I wonder if it is a good approach? According to MSDN:

> It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create performance issues.

I don't need to collect everything in the application, but only destroy several objects (`Bitmap`'s). Can I somehow tell GC to collect only these objects? Or maybe there is another way to optimize this process?

Comment: Can't you reuse the bitmaps so you wouldn't have to create new ones all the time?

Comment: The Bitmap class is the singular .NET class that reminds you without fail that calling Dispose() is important.  Miss just one and the odds your program bombs with OOM *significantly* increase.  The class is entirely too small (24 bytes) to timely trigger a GC by itself.  A memory profiler tends to be unhelpful, it only shows you that you used bitmaps (you already know it does) and a huge chunk of unmanaged memory without details.  A thorough code review is required to find the bug.  Can't get help with that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messing with the garbage collector is always a tricky one, and should in almost all cases be avoided.

From a performance perspective the best is to avoid involving the GC at all as much as possible by re-using your objects and buffers. This often comes at the price of increased complexity, if possible at all, so it is a trade-off.

Otherwise the recommended approach would be to design your application to make it easy for the GC:

- Make sure you de-reference your objects as early as possible when you no longer need them, so they can be collected quickly. With some luck, as generation 0 or 1.
- Call Dispose on objects that implements it before de-referencing them, to avoid the GC having to keep the object around to invoke the finalizer.

Since I suspect you already do that, what remains is thorough performance testing. If you release some large objects at infrequent, and hence hard for the GC to predict, intervals and you can show that your application performs better (whatever that means) if you call GC.Collect(), then go ahead.

As far as I know, you can not control what the GC collects. You cannot even be sure it will collect your just released large objects when calling GC.Collect(), if they have made it into GC generation 1 or 2. That is why you have to test and make measurements of your specific use cases.

A question is if it actually matters for your application that it takes a few seconds for the GC to catch up and memory usage to go down?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it sometimes can cause `OutOfMemoryException` even on my development machine, and client's machines could have lower amount of available memory. Anyway, thank you for the suggestions and explanations, I'll mark your answer, as it's the most complete one.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksey, and sorry for missing your mention of `OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a 'Using' on anything that implements IDispose, do it. The alternative is that your program is badly organised to manage the process regrettably.

You should always let the Framework mange disposing where possible.

Questions to ask yourself:

- Am I creating new instances of objects instead of reusing existing?
- Can I set any objects to null after use? Or dispose of them entirely?
- What line is causing the leak? I recommend running the program and
  switch taskmanger aside - then step through - you'll see the ramps in
  usage in real time as you step through.
- Can I batch? If I'm managing 100 images, can I split into 10 groups
  of 10?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'using' scope for this process.

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
{
/// your code
}
```

Comment: `using` scope is only a convenient way to guarantee `Dispose` will be called after the block. I'm actually use it, but it does not solve the problem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Thios does not trigger the garbage collector, it just marks the objet as "ready to collect"